# Best way of finding aspect ratio

Tags: graphics, haskell

I'm writing a simple OpenGL game with Haskell. Whenever the user resizes the window I get their width and height. I need to calculate the largest width and height that fits inside their window while maintaining the W/H ratio of 1.6.

This is what I wrote. It works but I don't think it's the best way of doing it in Haskell. Can someone suggest some alternatives:

```
fixedRatio = 1.6

keepRatio (w,h) = head [(floor w',floor h') | w' <- [w, h*fixedRatio], h' <- [h, w/fixedRatio], w' <= w, h' <= h, w'/h' == fixedRatio ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it with a guard (condition):

```
keepRatio (w,h) | w > expectedWidth = (floor expectedWidth, h)
                | otherwise         = (w, floor(fromIntegral w / fixedRatio))
                where expectedWidth = fromIntegral h * fixedRatio
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
keepRatio (w,h) = min sizeByWidth sizeByHeight
   where sizeByWidth = (w, (w * 5) `div` 8)
         sizeByHeight = ((h*8) `div` 5, h)
```

This assumes that you only need the aspect ratio to the nearest pixel.

Comment: In this case, can we say `min` instead of `minBy (comparing fst)`?

Comment: Yes!  I'd forgotten that instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a,b).  Edited accordingly.